# How to combine 2 JSON files in Angular 8

Tags: arrays, json, angular, angular8

in my current Angular 8 project I have to connect two JSON files. After connecting, the new file should be uploaded to a server.
The files are selected via two HTML input labels.

```
<input id="file_1" name="file_1" type="file">
<input id="file_2" name="file_2" type="file">

<button buttonLabel="convert" (click)="postJson()"></button>
```

Start of JSON 1:

```
{
    "result": 0,
    "deviceInfos": [{
            "deviceIndex": 1,
            "info": {
                "name": "Test1234",
                "type": "Test",
                "serialNumber": 123456,
                "canBus": 0,
                "canPos": 1,
                .....
```

Start of JSON 2:

```
{
    "result": 0,
    "deviceDescriptions": [
    {
            "deviceIndex": 1,
            "deviceTypeId": 34567,
            "descriptions": [{
                    "name": "Temp.Test",
                    "unitName": "",
                    "dataType": "string",
                    "constraints": {
                        "maxLen": 40,
                        "regExpr": "^([-_ a-zA-Z0-9]{0,40})$"
                    },
                    ......
```

My actual component:

```
export class JsonConverterComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  postJson() {
    this.http.post(url, jarray)
      .subscribe(res => 
        console.log(res.json(

        ))
      );
  }

}
```

I have no idea how to access both files after clicking the button and then combine them.

How I can do this?

Comment: Have you tried the solution?

Comment: Yes it works fine. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
this.result = this.json1.deviceInfos.flatMap(item => ({
  ...item,
  description : this.json2.deviceDescriptions.filter( x => x.deviceIndex == item.deviceIndex)
}));
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ndurhk?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**